# Functional programming tutorials

Tags: functional-programming

Implementing the very first scala example I ran into some problems probably tipical for those who dipped into the declarative style functional programming from imperative style. I just can't lose the habit of mutating data ;) Are there some tutorials that help me introduce the functional programming style? Or is scala tutorial enough? (I've read a quarter of it yet)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One of the most celebrated tutorials for the functional programming language Haskell is [Learn you a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/), I would seriously recommend it.